# How to count each word in a string without .split()?

Tags: java

Given a String sentence entered by the user. Print each word on a separate line with the word #. For example, If the sentence "The cat in the hat" was entered, the following would be the output

> word #1: The
>   word #2: cat
>   word #3: in
>   word #4: the
>   word #5: hat

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

String sentence;
String words = "";
int count = 1;

sentence = input.nextLine();


for (int i = 1; i < sentence.length(); i++)
{
  if (sentence.charAt(i) == ' ')
    count++;
}
{
  words = sentence.substring(0,sentence.indexOf(' '));
  System.out.println(words);
}
```

Comment: try stringtokenizer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: I can't use stringtokenizer because I haven't learned it?

Comment: You didn't state why you can't use `.split()`.

Comment: because my teacher said I could do it without .split() plz help Thanks

Comment: First of all, you ignore the first character, by starting at index 1. Use `int i = 0; `.

Comment: @AlexSolomons you have some crazy stuff going on with your brackets at the bottom there. why are the last 2 lines in their own code segment with brackets? It doesn't make sense syntactically.

Comment: I can't use it because my teacher would think I copied it off the internet.

Comment: what you actually need array of words or simple split?

Answer (score 4):

```
String s = "The cat in the hat";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(s);
int wordNum = 1;
while(scan.hasNext()){
    String temp = scan.next();
    System.out.println("word#" + wordNum + ": \t" + temp);
    wordNum++;
}
```

or

```
System.out.print("word#" + wordNum + ": \t" + temp + "\t");
```

if you want all on the same line

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this, but his answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, keep track of the starting index of each word (e.g. store it in a variable). Whenever you hit a new space, print out the word using substring with the number appended to it.

A few cases you may want to handle. If the sentence begins or ends with a bunch of spaces, you need to handle this without printing anything or incrementing your word count. You will need to do the same if there are multiple spaces between words.

Answer (score 0):

The following code separates the word of given string

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class StringTokenDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    String sentence=sc.nextLine();

    StringTokenizer tokenizer=new StringTokenizer(sentence," ");
   int i=1;
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        String token=(String)tokenizer.nextToken();
        System.out.println("#word"+i+" "+token);
        i++;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: OP has said that he cannot use String tokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right place to post homework, anyway the below code do what you want. If you want to print the words you need to store them, for example in a list or in an array.

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
String sentence = "The cat in the hat ";

int pos = 0;
int lastCharIndex = sentence.length() - 1 ; 
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++){
        char cur = sentence.charAt(i);
        //start to collect char for word only if 
        //the starting char is not a space  
        if(sentence.charAt(pos) == ' ' ){
            pos+=1;
            continue;
        }
        //continue the cycle if the current char is not a space
        // and it isn't the last char
        if(cur != ' ' && i != lastCharIndex){
            continue;       
        }
        //last word could not terminate with space
        if(i == lastCharIndex && cur != ' '){
            i+=1;
        }

        String word = sentence.substring(pos,i);
        pos=i;
        words.add(word);    
    }

    System.out.println(words);
```

the code also take care if extra space between word or at the end of the sentence. Hope this can help.

Answer (score -1):

did you try stringbuilder, or you can add all the elements in a arraylist and then count them. or count the chars.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
String sentence;
 String words = "";
  int count = 0;
  for(char c : input.toCharArray()){
   count++;
     }
 System.out.println("The word count is "+ count);
```